# Automorphisms of matrix algebras and Picard Group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, picard-group

**Notation.** In what follows, $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$, $n\geq 1$ is an integer, $\mathcal{B}=(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ is a fixed basis of $R^n$, and $e_{ij}$ is the usual elementary endomorphism, namely the unique endomorphism of $R^n$ such that $e_{ij}(e_k)=\delta_{j,k}e_i$.

In other words, the matrix of $e_{ij}$ wrt to $\mathcal{B}$ is the usual elementary matrix $E_{ij}$.

**Context.** The relationship between the outer automorphism group of the $R$-algebra ${\rm End}(R^n)$ and the $n$-torsion of the Picard group of $R$ is well-known (this can even be generalized to Azumaya algebras). The standard result is that there is a group isomorphism between ${\rm Out}({\rm End}(R^n))$ and the subgroup $\mathcal{P}_n(R)$ of ${\rm Pic}(R)$ consisting of isomorphisms classes of $R$-modules $M$ satisfying $M^n\simeq_R R^n.$ (For those who are not familiar with Picard groups: this is the group of isomorphism classes of projective modules of rank one, and the group law is induced by the tensor product). It can be shown that $\mathcal{P}_n(R)\subset {\rm Pic}_n(R)$.

In the paper [Automorphisms of matrix algebras of commutative rings](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/0024379580902219?token=31F671979DC8A4AAA903415DFE13CD46843455BF95B5D579876756ED3E4AF8048A7D8CCFB6B2582AD194F2C8E26E2FE1&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20230504142204), Isaacs provides a direct proof of thie group isomorphism above.

The isomorphism  is the usual one (the one used also in the more general case of Azumaya algebras): it sends the conjugacy class of $\theta$ to the isomorphism class of the $R$-module  $S_\theta=\lbrace v\in {\rm End}(R^n)\mid u\circ v =v \circ \theta(u) \ \mbox{ for all }u\in {\rm End}(R^n) \rbrace$.

**Motivation.** Out of curiosity, I tried (really hard) to write down the inverse isomorphism, but I found it very difficult for various reasons. In particular, the proof of surjectivity of the map above seems really too complicated for such a little result (it uses a lot of cumbersome ad hoc computations  and various intermediate results), so I have decided to come with a direct proof of my own.

**My work so far.**

If $\theta$ is an automorphism of $R$-algebras of $\mathrm{End}(R^n)$, set $M_\theta={\rm Im}(\theta(e_{11})).$ I can show that the isomorphism class of $M_\theta$ only depends  of the conjugacy class of $\theta$.

If $M$ is an $R$-module satisfying $M^n\simeq R^n$, fix an isomorphism $\varphi: M^n\to R^n$.

Set $\iota_i:M\to M^n, x\mapsto (0,\ldots,0,x,0,\ldots,0)$, where $x$ is in position $i$, and let $\pi_j:M^n\to M$ the projection on the $j-th$ component.

Then, one may show that there is a unique $R$-algebra automorphism $\theta_M$ of ${\rm End}(R^n)$ such that $\theta_M(e_{ij})=\varphi\circ \iota_i\circ\pi_j\circ \varphi^{-1}$ for all $i,j$.

I can show that the conjugacy class of $\theta_M$ does not depend on the choice of $\varphi$ and only depends on the isomorphism class of $M$.

Hence, we get a map $\alpha:  \mathcal{P}_n(R)\to {\rm Out}({\rm End}(R^n))$, sending the isomorphism class of $M$ to the conjugacy class of $\theta_M$.

I can show that $\alpha$ is a bijective map, where the inverse map $\beta$ sends the conjugacy class of $\theta$ to the isomorphism class of $M_\theta.$

Finally, here comes my question.

**Question.** I would like to prove that $\alpha$ is a group morphism. However, despite all my efforts I did not succeed at the moment.

I would appreciate some help on this.

**Remark.** I am aware that all of my work is probably Isaac's proof in disguise, but curiously, my point of view allows me to prove really easily the surjectivity of $\alpha$, that I couldn't see with Isaac's arguments.

**Side Question.** At the moment, the relationship between $M_\theta$ and $S_\theta$ is not clear to me. Does anyone see what it could be ?